# Can astronauts in currently planned pressure suits survive a cabin which cannot be repressurized?

Tags: spacesuits, eva, docking-port, emergency

Imagine the Crew Dragon (or Stariner or Orion) has just achieved orbit. Due to a manufacturing flaw or a meteor, the window suddenly blows out. All 6 of the crew manages to get their suit visor's closed so they are OK. 
Now What? They can't reenter with an open window.

So they go to ISS & dock. New problem is, if they open the hatch, the air in the station will go out their window. So the ISS crew seals and depressurizes the compartment inside the hatch so it's an airlock. (can that be done?)

Next  Problem: Can a crew member shut off his umbilical before unplugging himself so the air in his suit won't rush out?

If he can, can all 6 of them live off residual air in their suits as they unplug, get through the hatch, close the hatch and pressurize the chamber?

In other words:
Can astronauts in currently planned pressure suits survive a cabin which cannot be repressurized?

Comment: Related https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/12734/how-long-does-it-take-to-get-frotakem-a-spacewalk-to-being-inside-the-iss-and-out-of

Comment: If the capsule is not pressurized, the hatch of the ISS compartment under pressure could not be opened anyway.

Comment: Instead of docking, they could berth the capsule near an EVA airlock and then EVA from the unpressurized capsule into the airlock.

Comment: Also, are we sure that the capsule couldn't reenter with a blown out window or in a depressurized state?

Comment: @Dragongeek the 'normal' response to a loss of cabin pressure would be to abort and re-enter. Not sure about the loss of a window or how credible of a failure that is. Human spacecraft windows are usually multi-pane/layer affairs.

Comment: Losing a window probably compromises heat shielding so that it isn't very safe for reentry, but depressurization doesn't necessary means such severe structural damage.

Comment: @Dragongeek An EVA using an IVA suit without a backpack for oxygen replacement and carbon dioxide removement?

Comment: About the window. Glass can have weird internal stresses. There was an incident where the lunar Excursion Module was sitting in the hanger and a window suddenly just popped into pieces. They never could figure out what happened. Eventually they just replaced it and hoped for the best.

Comment: A meteor could punch a hole in the hull. Also if there were a control anomaly, a collision could punch in the hatch, deforming it and making it unsealable.

Comment: Most of the depressurization emergencies I can think of would eventually require an EVA for survival. I think it's nuts that they don't have little 20 minute back packs for air, CO2 removal and power. Otherwise they will be forced to try it with residual air in the suit. That might not even be possible if there is no shut-off valve on the umbilical. I think in most cases those pressure suits just give them a wait-to-die situation.